# Geomesa and Hadoop compatibility

Tags: hadoop, geomesa

I need to store raster data on a cluster with CDH 6.2.0 either on HBase 2.1.0 or on Hadoop HDFS 3.0.0. I also need to connect rasters to GeoServer (2.16) to publish map layers. I tried to integrate the elements with GeoMesa (2.4.0) but the installation wasn't successful. According to the documentation only HBase 1.3.x and 1.4.x are supported and I didn't even find any reference to Hadoop 3.0.0. Is this solution compatible with my cluster?

Answer (score 1):

many Apache products are broadly compatible.  So far, other users have reported GeoMesa working on Hadoop 3.x clusters, so that part is not a problem.

There are API differences between HBase 1.3/1.4 and HBase 2.x.  At the moment, there are some PRs for HBase 2.x support.  You can find out more by reaching out to the GeoMesa community on Gitter or the mailing lists (https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa#join-the-community) or by looking for support at https://www.geomesa.org/.

Answer (score 1):

Jim's answer is correct with regards to vector data, which is GeoMesa's main focus. However, GeoMesa's (deprecated) raster functionality only supports Accumulo. You might want to consider using [GeoTrellis](https://geotrellis.io/) as a solution.

Comment: I had already planned to integrate GeoTrellis to perform further processing on the rasters so it would be great if this tool could be the solution. But at the moment I can't see how GeoTrellis could help me in connecting GeoServer with my cluster's services. I searched for a GeoServer plugin or extension but I didn't find anything that seemed appropriate.